# MySql Select statement distinct latest date value based on Primary ID of Keyword

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Basically I have a list of SEO keywords in one table and their Ranking including Date entered in another table.

### keywords

```
[keywordID(PKID)] [keyword]
----------------------------
1                 SEO
2                 Vancouver Homes
```

### keywordRanking

```
[rankingID(PKID)] [keywordID(FKID)] [ranking] [rankingDate(timestamp)]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 1                 3         Jan 01, 2010
2                 1                 5         Jan 02, 2010
3                 1                 8         Jan 03,2010
4                 2                 4         Jan 01, 2010
```

Here are the results I want. I want the latest ranking of a keyword based on its latest ranking Date without duplicates.

For the data above, it should return:

```
                  [keywordID] [rankingID] [ranking] [rankingDate] 
                  -----------------------------------------------
 SEO              1           3           8         Jan 03, 2010
 Vancouver Homes  4           2           4         Jan 01, 2010
```

What would the statement be to select the latest ranking for a keyword? Right now I have it returning duplicate rows for the keywordID.

Please ask if more information is required here is my current sql statement.

```
SELECT * 
  from keywords,
       keywordRankings 
 WHERE keywords.keywordID = keywordRankings.keywordID;
```

My current solution which works for me is...

```
SELECT s1.keywordID, keyword, rankingDate, ranking
FROM keywords s1, keywordRankings
WHERE keywordRankingRecord = (
SELECT MAX( s2.keywordRankingRecord )
FROM keywordRankings s2
WHERE s1.keywordID = s2.keywordID )
```

Comment: shouldn't that first result row read 'SEO, 1, **3**, 8, Jan 03,2010' - or am I missing something?

Comment: @Martin - Thank you, that is correct and thank you to whoever edited my post to look so pretty.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental idea behind finding the maximum among a group is explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

```
SELECT k.keyword,
       r1.*
FROM   keyword AS k
       LEFT JOIN keywordRanking AS r1
         ON k.keywordid = r1.keywordid
       LEFT JOIN keywordRanking AS r2
         ON k.keywordid = r2.keywordid
            AND r1.rankingdate < r2.rankingdate
WHERE  r2.ranking IS NULL
```

yields

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| keyword         | keywordID | rankingID | ranking | rankingDate         |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| SEO             |         1 |         3 |       8 | 2010-01-03 00:00:00 | 
| Vancouver Homes |         2 |         4 |       4 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | 
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: SELECT keyword, r1 . *
FROM keywords AS k
LEFT JOIN keywordRankings AS r1 ON k.keywordid = r1.keywordid
LEFT JOIN keywordRankings AS r2 ON k.keywordid = r2.keywordid
AND r1.rankingdate < r2.rankingdate
WHERE r2.ranking IS NULL
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Your statement didn't work out for me though, because I found it returned duplicate results on keyword ID, I've posted my own solution at the moment keyword  keywordRankingRecord  keywordID  ranking  rankingDate
test  4  1  5  2010-09-30 10:08:56
test  5  1  8  2010-09-30 10:08:56
2nd keyword  6  2  2  2010-09-30 10:08:56